# How to add a link inside a text In css?

Tags: css

Following is the code for adding a like tag along/ inside a p tag

```
<span>
<p>By clicking here I agree to All</p> 
<a href="#">Terms and Conditions </a> 
<p> of this website</p>
</span>
```

and inside the css I'm doing something like this:

```
    span {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;

      p {
        margin: 0;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: blue;
        margin: 0 0.3rem;
      }
    }
```

But the issue here is that when I shrink/ resize the window the text is collapsing.

How can I prevent this? or how can I add a link in-between a text element so that they all behave similarly on resizing

This is the issue:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Look how they are collapsing. I want them to be in a single line and I want the Terms and Conditions to be a link.

I want them to be something like this:

[image]

So that even if you resize the window they sticks to each other

Another Example:

[image]

Comment: FYI, your HTML is invalid. You can't put paragraph elements inside spans. Your post is also missing the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put links directly inside the paragraph, as such:

```html
<span>
<p>By clicking here I agree to All <a href="#">Terms and Conditions </a> of this website</p> 
</span>
```

Comment: The problem here has nothing to do with a newline, and everything to do with flex layout. Why would removing a newline fix a flex layout issue?